# Multiline if else tmux

Tags: tmux

I'm using tmux 3.1c. I want to know if I can do something like

```
if-shell <condition> {
    # true
    cmd1

    cmd2
} {
    # false
    cmd1

    cmd2
}
```

Or should I separate the code in two `if-shell` because I think I can only have one parenthesis in case the condition is true.

I also want to know if I have to use `; \` to separate the commands, if I have to use `\` in a white line like between `cmd1` and `cmd2` and if I have to use it on the line with a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the following binding in 3.0a and it was ok:

```
bind-key x if-shell '[ #{pane_index} -eq 0 ]' {
    # comment
    select-pane -R

    send-keys hello1
 } {
    # comment
    select-pane -L

    send-keys hello2
 }
```

I would have expected to be able to use braces instead of quotes for the `[ #{pane_index} -eq 0 ]` string too, but this didn't work, and might need a later version than I have.

Comment: It's worth to note that the space between `}` and `{` characters **is** required.